# Who were the Magharians?

Tags: history, communities

Title says it all. Who were the Magharians? It seems like they were some group of Pre-Christianity Jews or something like that that lived in caves?

Comment: Where is that name used?

Comment: I've seen it in various papers that I've read about Jewish History

Comment: What did those papers say about them? Any context you provide in your question will only help people answer it.

Comment: do you mean the mugrabi?

Comment: Is this on topic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any of many groups that lived in or used caves could be given the name *Magharians* (from Arabic).

The tenth century (CE) Karaite [Jacob Qirqisani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Qirqisani) described them as a pre-Christian group with distinctive views about angels, creation and biblical anthropomorphisms.

According to Muslim scholar [al-Biruni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Biruni) (973-1048) they used a lunar calendar and observed Rosh ha-Shanah and Passover only on a Wednesday.

In modern times, there have been some suggestions that those using the Dead Sea Scrolls and the caves at Qumran may have been Magharians, though there are several other theories.

A couple of links: [1](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/rak/courses/427/minutes04.htm) and [2](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=exAVAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA148&lpg=PA148&dq=magharians+dead+sea+scrolls&source=bl&ots=Crm2VE9qpk&sig=GO4WVsCH0JIzoUZHqB2u7YnHpNY&hl=en&ei=t4dqTvq6NtGq8AO_y_RA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=magharians%20dead%20sea%20scrolls&f=false)

Comment: Henry, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the informative answer! I look forward to seeing you around.